# How do I remove the vertical scroll bar from this Typewriter script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a question about this [Typewriter script](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/) that I found.

Here is the code:

```js
function setupTypewriter(t) {
  var HTML = t.innerHTML;

  t.innerHTML = "";

  var cursorPosition = 0,
    tag = "",
    writingTag = false,
    tagOpen = false,
    typeSpeed = 100,
    tempTypeSpeed = 0;

  var type = function() {
    if (writingTag === true) {
      tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }

    if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "<") {
      tempTypeSpeed = 0;
      if (tagOpen) {
        tagOpen = false;
        writingTag = true;
      } else {
        tag = "";
        tagOpen = true;
        writingTag = true;
        tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
      }
    }
    if (!writingTag && tagOpen) {
      tag.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }
    if (!writingTag && !tagOpen) {
      if (HTML[cursorPosition] === " ") {
        tempTypeSpeed = 0;
      } else {
        tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 50;
      }
      t.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }
    if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === ">") {
      tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 50;
      writingTag = false;
      if (tagOpen) {
        var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
        t.appendChild(newSpan);
        newSpan.innerHTML = tag;
        tag = newSpan.firstChild;
      }
    }

    cursorPosition += 1;
    if (cursorPosition < HTML.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
    }
  };

  return {
    type: type
  };
}

var typer = document.getElementById('typewriter');

typewriter = setupTypewriter(typewriter);
typewriter.type();
```

```css
.var-highlight {
  color: #C0AD60;
}

.string-highlight {
  color: rgba(253, 149, 90, 0.8);
}

#typewriter {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Courier New";
}

#typewriter:after {
  content: "|";
  -webkit-animation: blink 500ms linear infinite alternate;
          animation: blink 500ms linear infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="typewriter">
<span class="var-highlight">var</span> object = {
    name: <span class="string-highlight">'Foo'</span>,
    type: <span class="string-highlight">'Bar'</span>,
    location: <span class="string-highlight">'Earth'</span>,
    properties:[<span class="string-highlight">'Javascript'</span>,
                <span class="string-highlight">'HTML'</span>,
                <span class="string-highlight">'CSS'</span>];
}; </pre>
```

Now the thing is that when this code starts to play, it creates a scroll bar at the right border.

[image: Screenshot]

**How can I remove that scrollbar?**

I just want to have the typewriter animation, so that it looks more smooth and more part of the website.